# 12.04 LTS apt-get hanging connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: 12.04, apt

I have a 12.04 LTS VPS that no longer seems to be able to `apt-get` anything. It connects ok for security patches, but on installing anything just hangs at `0%` trying to connect to `us.archive.ubuntu.com`. I tried pinging `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and that's working. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe the mirror is down, have you tried another server?

Comment: What does the output to `wget --debug http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/project/trace/pepo.canonical.com` do?

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue led me to another post on forcing apt-get to acquire IPv4 connection which resolved my issue.
I have quoted the answer from the other forum for convenience.

> Add `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` when running apt-get.
>
> If you want to make the setting persistent just create
>   /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4 and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";`in it.
>
> Config options Acquire::ForceIPv4 and Acquire::ForceIPv6 were added to
>   version 0.9.7.9~exp1 (see bug 611891) which is available in Ubuntu
>   Saucy (released in october 2013) and Debian Jessie (not released yet).

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method

Answer (score 0):

Updating this for future readers, I found out I could fix it by switching to prefer v4 over v6 using /etc/gai.conf.